# calling dropdown dynamically for selecting date in html

Tags: javascript

```
  <select  value="dt" name="previousYear">
  <option value="2007">2007</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>
  <option value="2009">2009</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2012">2013</option>
  <option value="2012">2014</option>
</select>
<select  value="dt" name="currentYear">
  <option value="2007">2007</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>
  <option value="2009">2009</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2012">2013</option>
  <option value="2012">2014</option>
</select>
<select  value="dt" name="nextYear">
  <option value="2007">2007</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>
  <option value="2009">2009</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2012">2013</option>
  <option value="2012">2014</option>
</select>
```

I have 3 drop down list like this previous year ,current year & next year How can i select the current year as a current year like if the current year is 2012 then it automatically have to select the 2012 when page loads can any one tell me the Javascript  code for selecting dynamikcally

Comment: You should remove value=dt from the select tag too

Answer (score 4):

Your markup seems incorrect . I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setYear()
{
 var d = new Date();
 var x = document.getElementById("currentYear");//for select box id="currentYear"
 x.value=d.getFullYear();
}
</script>
```

Call it like :

```
<body onload="setYear()">
<!-- your markup -->
</body>
```

Call the above function on page load to set current year for the select box. 
I would suggest you to [learn Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp) for better understanding as its a basic example.Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you tell me how to callfunction as i am new to javascript please explain me allobrate

Comment: Don't have inline handlers. Instead use `window.onload=function() {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You should use something as

```
var d = new Date();

var cur = document.getElementById('currentYear');
var prev = document.getElementById('previousYear');
var next = document.getElementById('nextYear');
var optionC, optionP, optionN;

for (var i = d.getFullYear() - 5; i <= d.getFullYear() + 5; i++) {
    optionC = document.createElement("option");
    optionC.setAttribute("value", i);
    optionC.innerHTML = i;
    cur.appendChild(optionC);
}

for (var i = d.getFullYear() - 10; i < d.getFullYear(); i++) {
    optionP = document.createElement("option");
    optionP.setAttribute("value", i);
    optionP.innerHTML = i;
    prev.appendChild(optionP);
}

for (var i = d.getFullYear() + 1; i <= d.getFullYear() + 10; i++) {
    optionN = document.createElement("option");
    optionN.setAttribute("value", i);
    optionN.innerHTML = i;
    next.appendChild(optionN);
}

cur.value = d.getFullYear();
prev.value = d.getFullYear() - 1;
next.value = d.getFullYear() + 1;​
```

Just add javascript function like

```
function setYear(obj)
{
    var prev = document.getElementById('previousYear');
    var next = document.getElementById('nextYear');   

    prev.value = Number(obj.value) - 1;
    next.value = Number(obj.value) + 1;
}
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cyDrs/2/)

Comment: How can i select default as a current year as a current year in HTML select what i have to write and there i have to display the previous 10 years and next 10 years when i select the drop down it shoul display

Comment: You mean you need to generate HTML dynamically ??

Comment: thank i need one more help jaychapani if i change the current year den it automatically have to change the previous year and next year if i select the current year as 2007 den previous year has to be 2006 and next year should be 2008 like that

Comment: I have a div class also how can i call that one How can i display the year of current year using dynamically in the div class ....
<div class="simpleDrop" style="width:55px;" id="CYearHold"></div>  
               <select id="CYear" class="inputControl simple" style="width:55px;"   name="currentYear" onChange="setYear1(this);">
                
               </select>
               </div>

Comment: @user1550575 I didn't get you

Comment: I have div between the select  that div is for diplaying the current year